# How do I print attributes of describe_cluster_snapshots in AWS Lambda using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

How do I print attributes of describe_cluster_snapshots in AWS Lambda using Python. Following print functions gives error:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import boto3
import datetime

source = boto3.client('redshift')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cluster_snaps=source.describe_cluster_snapshots(SnapshotType='manual')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks! ... **gives error** is not a helpful problem description!

Comment: How about `cluster_snaps.__dict__`?

Comment: What is the error?